# How do I place text in Jquery Mobile in alignment with the controls on a form?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Jquery Mobile nicely lays out controls in a grid. I would the text "12345678" outlined in red in the image below to sit right above the textbox and left aligned. I can't see how to do it.

[image]

The image was generated with this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/958Gr/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting disabled='true' and value="12345678" you can get something decent.  The account number will still show as as field, but then you can theme it differently.  See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/den232/7hmYn/

Good Luck!

```
    <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
<div data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme='c'>
<label for="Phone" >Account ID</label>      
<input id="Phone" name="Phone" type="text" disabled='true' value="12345678"  />

</div></div>

<div class="ui-body  ui-body-c">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="Email">Email Address</label>
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Email Address field is required." id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />

</div> </div>

<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="Email">Email Address</label>
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Email Address field is required." id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />

</div> </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may Use Two-column grids as in this updated jsfiddle:[link](http://jsfiddle.net/958Gr/10/)

Comment: In your fiddle, it's not left-aligned with the input fields.